# Symfony 2 Forms : Check existence of a FormView method

Tags: forms, symfony

I would like to check in the twig file the existence of comment method in FormView so  I can write :

```
{{ form_label(form.comment) }}
```

so :

```
{% if xxxxxx %}

   {{ form_label(form.comment) }}<br/>

   {{ form_errors(form.comment) }}

   {{ form_widget(form.comment)}} 

{% endif %}
```

thank you

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: if comment does not exist there is an exception

Comment: I would like to test the existence before displaying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it :

```
{% if yourvar is defined %}
 ...
{% endif %}
```